# Civicrm : How to send Automatically Thank you email On adding a Contribution payment?

Tags: civicrm, civicrm-extension

When we add a Contribution payment using Record Payment need to send Thank you email automatically.

I tried CiviRules Extension.This Extension use like trigger for action but I am not getting perfect way to do this. any other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two way:

Option 1:

There is an option to send a receipt when you add payment in contribution.
so you can use this API and set send receipt option 1

Option 2:

Install two Extension 1) CiviRule 2) Civi Email- Api

Now You can create your custom rules and trigger send email, you have to install email - API for send email action.